# Could not find font Liberation Sans in MovableText::setFontName

Tags: ros, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When run 'roslaunch xxx_moveit_config demo.launch', I can not open RViz,and report 'Could not find font Liberation Sans in MovableText::setFontName',who can tell me how to do with it? I use Jade.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287427/could-not-find-font-liberation-sans-in-movabletext::setfontname/) by [ddddddddong](https://answers.ros.org/users/34487/ddddddddong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A change to that font was introduced in RViz some time ago now and announced in [[notice] Removal of Arial in rviz caused breaking changes](https://discourse.ros.org/t/notice-removal-of-arial-in-rviz-caused-breaking-changes/2791). A related/duplicate question on ROS Answers would be #q271750.

The details about what is going on are in those two posts.

> I use Jade.

As to the MoveIt issue: that was resolved in consecutive fixes to the code base, but as ROS Jade has been EOL for quite some time now, it could well be that those fixes never made it to Jade MoveIt.

If you have the possibility, upgrading to ROS Kinetic would probably be the best solution here.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ddddddddong](https://answers.ros.org/users/34487/ddddddddong/) on 2018-04-04**:
Thank U very much.I've solved this problem by updating my RViz('apt-get install update' & 'apt-get install ros-jade-rviz')

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-04**:
Ok. Good to hear you got it to work. Do note that Jade is EOL though, so it won't receive any more updates to any of the ROS packages in that ROS release.